# Stop crashing css file in common layout page

Tags: html, css

Im design a webpage with common layout page.Common layout page has different css files and other pages have different css files for each.
Problem is, Common layout page css file attributes and other css files attributes crashes.then design got mess.
Any ideas to solve this problem. Thanks you..

layout css one attributes

```
.newstyle
    {
        font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        font-size: 15px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        FLoat:left;

    }
```

Other page css attributes

```
.newstyle
    {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        color: #000000;
        text-decoration: none;

    }
```

I need to add both attributes, there are lot of attributes are like this. any solution to stop merge them?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. First, show us a little of your code and how you tried to accomplish what you desire. Without code or what you've tried we can't help you to get a solution.

Comment: Edited  now check it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the key here is the way you manage your stylesheets. Create a general stylesheet where you define the styles that are the same in every page.

For example (general.css):

```
div.content {
   width: 50em;
   background: lightblue;
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

Then you can make per page a different stylesheet, for example (page1.css)

```
div.content {
   color: red;
   font-size: 1.25em;
}
```

And (page2.css)

```
div.content {
    color: blue;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In the pages, you call the stylesheets you need:

```
<!-- page1.php -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page1.css" />

<!-- page2.php -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="general.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="page2.css" />
```

**ALTERNATIVE**

As an alternative, you could use multiple classes. As an example:
    div.content {
       width: 50em;
       background: lightblue;
       border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    .page1 {
       color: red;
       font-size: 1.25em;
    }
    .page2 {
        color: blue;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

You then only need one stylesheet, and call two classes on your div, for example:

```
<!-- page1.php -->
<div class="content page1">...</div>

<!-- page2.php -->
<div class="content page2">...</div>
```